# Ardunio Curve Tracer Question

Tags: transistors

I am trying to follow this guide to make a curve tracer with an ardunio: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-BiCMOS-Curve-Tracer/

If I use this these op amps: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2341.pdf with the 5v supply will it still work? Also If I wanted to supply the transistor 12 volts how would I do that, couldn't I supply that to the op amps then on the inputs to the ardunio step it down to 5v?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the datasheet of the opa2341:

- rail-to-rail input and output range
- supply 2.5 - 5.5 V

That should would work just fine in my opinion.

If you want to use a 12 V supply, feed it to the power jack on the Arduino board, this will take the 12V to an on-board regulator which will make 5 V from that 12 V.
I would just connect the suppy pins of the opamps to any of teh 5 V VDD pins on the arduino board. The opamp's current consumption will be low enough so that you can "borrow" it from the Arduino's supply.

It is only safe to feed 12 V to the Power jack, the rest of the circuits (Arduino microcontroller + opamps) CANNOT handle 12 V, they will break !
Only the regulator connected to the power jack can handle 12 V.

Comment: The second part of your answer does not address the OP's desire to apply 12V *to the transistor under test*.

Comment: It was a bit unclear to me what was asked. Anyway transistor testing at 12 V would complicate things enormously as the Arduino cannot handle 12 V.